# Unable to create instance of class in sub-package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, visibility

Why I can not create in class KeyboardController instance of Frame like:
    Frame frame=new Frame();
It is not recognized by IDEA.
Is it because classes in lower package can not see and work with classes in higher package?
And how should I workaround it?
All classes and functions are set to maximal visibility - public

Directory tree:

[image: directory tree]

Comment: Do you have the correct imports?

Comment: Based on the presence of `META-INF` I'm assuming `Frame` and `Main` are in the default package (i.e. they have no package). Classes in packages cannot access classes in the default package.

Comment: @Mark yes, IDEA is automatically creating imports

Comment: @Slaw yes it is in default package. Should I all my files put into new package like "java", and it will fix problem?

Comment: Yes, moving the classes into a package will allow you to import them and then use them normally. You should, however, avoid naming the package `java`.

Comment: For anything other than throwaway code, you should always put all your classes into named packages.  But not packages beginning with "java".

Comment: Please read up on packages and why they're important. This is key foundational knowledge that you must know to move forward.